# python - argparse error: unrecognized argument when pass integer argument

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to pass the arguments to tensorflow parameter. 
if nothing in to command line pass the default in code.

script -

```
import argparse
import tensorflow as tf
import sys
import numpy as np
DEFAULT_SEED = 42
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some parameters.')
parser.add_argument('-s','--seed', help='random seed', type=int, default=DEFAULT_SEED)
args=parser.parse_args()
tf.set_random_seed(args.seed)
```

-error message

```
usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [-h] [-s SEED]ipykernel_launcher.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -f C:\Users\shin\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime\kernel-f7591362-5cb0-4a7f-ba51-b6ceac2ee819.json

An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.
```

this error occurs at args=parser.parse_args().
how i can fix it?

Comment: the error says that the problem is '-f', not '-s'. How do you run the above script?

Comment: I'm trying run cell using jupyter notebook. there is no -f.

Comment: If you put the script in a file and execute it, does it work?

Comment: I fix the code **args=parser.parse_known_args()** then fix the error in that line. but still error occurs at final line of the code, about **AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'seed'**

Comment: read the ``parser.parse_known_args`` documentation.

Comment: `args=parser.parse_args()` assumes the args are in `sys.argv` and unless you specify the arguments in Jupyter `sys.argv` is filled in for the `ipykernel_launcher.py`. If you are testing you can pass `args=parser.parse_args(['-s', something])`